# What does Wind Walk allow you to do on your turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

In the spell description for Wind Walk, we see that

> The only actions a creature can tale in this form are the Dash action or to revert to its normal form. (PHB p.288)

There are no explicit restrictions mentioned aside from that.  Also note that

> Anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus action. (PHB p.189)

However, Wind Walk does not exactly stop you from taking actions; it limits your options to the Dash action.  It's not clear to me if the effect qualifies as depriving the creature of its action.

Additionally, reactions have no such limitations as far as I can see, so even if bonus actions are not prevented, it seems as if reactions are fair game.

The PHB also lists several potential "free actions" (p.190) that the player may take on their turn.

It seems to me that these things may violate the spirit of the spell, and I would probably rule that creatures under Wind Walk could not, for example, make opportunity attacks, use Wild Shape, cast spells, or otherwise interact with the world in a way that wind could not.  However, my curiosity has gotten the better of me.

Is there anything in the rules or errata that specifically forbids taking bonus actions, reactions, or "free actions" while using Wind Walk?

Comment: To clarify, would you expect a Wind Walker to be able to cast spells with only Verbal components? I think the regular action and bonus action flavors are out, but you certainly seem to make a good point with reactions.

Comment: @JoelHarmon that's a good point about spells; in a gaseous form, it seems unlikely that one would be able to do the verbal component.  Material components would be sketchy as well if you cannot directly interact with other objects.  Somatic parts may be the most likely to work, but only if the form retains a humanoid shape.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### A bonus action *is* an action

PHB p. 189:

> Various class features, spells, and other abilities let you
>   take an additional **action** on your turn called a bonus
>   action.

### A reaction *is* an action

PHB p. 190:

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow
>   you to take a special **action** called a reaction.

### Other Activity on your turn *is not* an action unless your DM says it is

PHB p. 190:

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require
>   neither your action nor your move.

*Wind walk* limits what you can do with your actions: be they normal, bonus or reactions. If you can dash with your bonus action, you can Dash twice on your turn (i.e. move 3x your speed).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any clarification in the rules or errata, but here is how I read the passages you quoted:

> The only actions a creature can take in this form are the Dash action or to revert to its normal form.

The spell *"deprives you of your ability to take actions"* other than Dash or revert to normal. Based on the other quote, I would argue that it *"also prevents you from taking a bonus action"* other than Dash or revert to normal. Since reverting to normal takes an action, that leaves only Dash as a possible bonus action for classes that have that option.